# How can I easily configure samba share in Debian Wheezy?

Tags: debian, samba

I have just installed a new Debian Wheezy and I am trying to create a new share. I am using KDE 4, and there in the folder preferences menu I found option to share the folder with Samba - it doesn't seem to do anything though!

Is there a GUI or some web based configuration tool available in Debian?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not familiar with a GUI to accomplish this but the steps to do this manually from a terminal aren't too bad. You just need to do the following:

#### Install Samba & required packages

```
sudo apt-get install smbfs samba
```

#### Edit the conf file `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

Make sure you have the following line in this file and that it's uncommented. It might be set to `security = share` be default.

```
security = user
```

Also in this file, in your "Share Definitions" section, set up a new share similar to the following:

```
[primary]
   comment = Guest access Share
   path = /mnt/primary
   writeable = yes
   valid users = @smb
   guest ok = no
```

This says that the share will be called "primary", the local path to the share directory is at `/mnt/primary`, authorized users can write, only users in the group smb are allowed, and anonymous guests cannot use this.

#### Testing setup with `testparm`

When you are done, save the file.  Then run `testparm` to see if there are any problems.

#### example testparm run

```
$ testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[homes]"
Processing section "[printers]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

[global]
    workgroup = MYGROUP
    server string = Samba Server Version %v
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 50
    cups options = raw

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    read only = No
    browseable = No

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = Yes
    browseable = No
```

#### Starting Samba

Lastly, restart the samba server:

```
/etc/init.d/samba restart
```

#### Client Setup (On Windows)

Choose map network drive from the "My Computer" screen. Then enter:

```
\\debian_box_ip_address\share_name
```

For example:

```
\\192.168.0.200\primary
```

Then choose "login with different credentials" and enter your Linux  username/password.

#### References

- [HOWTO: Setting up an SMB share on Debian Squeeze](http://pcprob.blogspot.com/2011/03/howto-setting-up-smb-share-on-debian.html)

Answer (score 4):

There is the [SWAT](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/SWAT.html) (Samba Web Administration Tool), from which can administer your samba server.

It can do everything in the chosen answer - less the client configuration - and more. Just install it, `sudo apt-get install swat`, and navigate to your server at port 901 (`192.168.x.x:901`) from a Web browser.

You need to log in as root per samba reqs.