# Add AFP shares to ext3 partition

Tags: ext3, hfs+

Is it possible to add an AFP service / protocol to an existing ext3 partition?  I have a linux server that I want to share with Apple clients.  The clients want to use TIME MACHINE which will only backup to AFP   (or a local disk)

I'm hoping there's something like a SAMBA service that I can just add

(Question corrected - originally said HFS by mistake instead of AFP)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Netatalk](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netatalk) on Linux machines to serve files to OS X computers with AFP. And of course you should use ext3/ext4 filesystem for that.

---

To install on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install netatalk
```

Installation on CentOS is slightly [more complicated](http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Netatalk_3.1.8_SRPM_for_Fedora_and_CentOS).

The configuration file is in `/etc/netatalk/AppleVolumes.default`. You will have to configure share and enable TimeMachine support (`tm` option).

---

Also mind that Apple is slowly [phasing out](https://www.afp548.com/2013/06/11/smb2-and-you-saying-goodbye-to-afp-in-os-x-mavericks/) AFP.

You can use TimeMachine to backup to SMB drives. Refer to [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107032/time-machine-backup-to-an-smb-share-mavericks) on Ask Different.

Answer (score -1):

[HFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_File_System) is a *file system*, not a service or protocol. You can *format* partitions on your Linux server with HFS, but then they're still only available locally on your Linux server. To make data available to a remote computer (e.g. your Apple clients), you could:

1. On your Linux server, format an external disk with HFS. Unplug the disk and hook it up to your Apple computer, then MacOS should be able to read it.
2. Or, create a network share (like [SMB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74231/how-can-i-easily-configure-samba-share-in-debian-wheezy) or [NFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo)) on your Linux computer - apparently [Time Machine can use network shares](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72331/how-to-make-time-machine-backups-over-network-without-os-x-server), although it's an unsupported feature.

Comment: You're right - (I'm new to Mac), I should have said AFP not HFS.  That said, can you time machine to an AFP protocol (on an ext3 disk)?

Comment: [AFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Filing_Protocol) is still a _network_ protocol, see the link to the [Apple SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72331/how-to-make-time-machine-backups-over-network-without-os-x-server) answer where this is explained.